# Trying to pull posts and comments from Facebook for project, but can't get everything (python, json)

Tags: python, json, facebook, pagination

I'm trying to pull posts and comments from Facebook for a project, but can't seem to pull everything. It seems that I get two links with previous and next

Here's my code:

```
import facebook
import requests

def some_action(post):
    #print posts['data']
    print(post['created_time'])

access_token = INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE
user = 'walkers'


graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

x = 0
while x < 900000:
    #while True:
    try:
        posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
        print (posts)

    except KeyError:
        break
    x = x+1
```

My results are something like this:

```
{u'paging': {u'next': u' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/53198517648/posts?limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdDr64IO8892JzsoPWiKkMDcF4lTDosOcP0H0ZB1mIpIW5EYRrCylZAji6ZBSCVBAVUYiS80oNtWtAL9GazXxRf0yva&access_token=INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE, u'previous': u' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/53198517648/posts?limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdCqTjKBhfOsNBoKe3CJbnM2gU2RvLEYLgAQt1pHEcERVeK4qiw1dQAFHjt2sSInSZAIioZCqotwLMx8azzfZClIuCN&since=1430997206&access_token=INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE'}, u'data': [{u'picture': u'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/11200605_10153202855322649_2472649283560371030_n.jpg?oh=50a0b3998e7bae8bb10c3a5f0854af46&oe=56556974', u'story': u'Walkers added 8 new photos to the album: 20 Years of Gary.', u'likes': {u'paging': {u'cursors': {u'after': u'MzgxNzk1MDQ4NjQ3MTI3', u'before': u'MTAxNTI0OTY1MDIwNDIyODI='}}, u'data': [{u'id': u'10152496502042282', u'name': u'Aaron Hanson'}, {u'id': u'10203040513950876', u'name': u'Gary GazRico Hinchliffe'}, {u'id': u'10152934096109345', u'name': u'Stuart Collister'}, {u'id': u'10152297022606059', u'name': u'Helen Preston'}, {u'id': u'326285380900188', u'name': u'Rhys Edwards'}, {u'id': u'10204744346589601', u'name': u'Aaron Benfield'}, {u'id': u'10200910780691953', u'name': u'Mike S Q Wilkins'}, {u'id': u'10204902354187051', u'name': u'Paul Owen Davies'}, {u'id': u'10152784755311784', u'name': u'Dafydd Ifan'}, {u'id': u'1517704468487365', u'name': u'Stephen Collier'}, {u'id': u'10202198826115234', u'name': u'John McKellar'}, {u'id': u'10151949129487143', u'name': u'Lucy Morrison'}, {u'id': u'1474199509524133', u'name': u'Christine Leek'}, {u'id': u'381795048647127', u'name': u'Sandra Taylor'}]}, u'from': {u'category': u'Product/Service', u'name':
```

These are the two links with the missing information:

```
u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/53198517648/posts?limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdDr64IO8892JzsoPWiKkMDcF4lTDosOcP0H0ZB1mIpIW5EYRrCylZAji6ZBSCVBAVUYiS80oNtWtAL9GazXxRf0yva&access_token=INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE', 

u'previous': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/53198517648/posts?limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdCqTjKBhfOsNBoKe3CJbnM2gU2RvLEYLgAQt1pHEcERVeK4qiw1dQAFHjt2sSInSZAIioZCqotwLMx8azzfZClIuCN&since=1430997206&access_token=INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE'
```

Obviously where I've put "INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE" I've removed the access token. Is there any way of getting all the data?

Comment: What's the problem with using the pagination links to get the second and subsequent links? It's not clear from your description (more info on paging here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging )

Comment: It seem that I can only pull the first 25 posts per comment. I can't figure out how to pull it all.

Comment: Comments per post? have you tried using the cursors (before/after) to load the second page of comments?